# Rails 5 + FactoryGirl + Rspec: helper method undefined

Tags: factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I have this RSpec file to run:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe FinancialManager::SalaryRecord::SomeRecordsController,
               type: :controller,
               financial_manager: true,
               salary_record: true,
               some_record: true do

  context "GET #index" do
    it "assigns all record in instance variable" do
      some_record =
        FactoryGirl.create(
          :valid_financial_manager_salary_record_some_record
        )
      get :index
      expect(assigns(:financial_manager_salary_record_some_records))
        .to eq([some_record])
    end
  end
end
```

which using this record model:

```
class FinancialManager::SalaryRecord::SomeRecord < ApplicationRecord
  sanitize = ->(s) { ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(s) }

  validates :level,
            presence: true,
            inclusion: {
              in: sanitize.call("levels")
            },
            numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

The model file above is calling a `levels` method which is a helper method I defined in `helpers` folder. When I run the RSpec file, I got this error:

```
Failure/Error:
       FactoryGirl.create(
         :valid_financial_manager_salary_record_some_record
       )

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `levels' for #<FinancialManager::SalaryRecord::SomeRecord:0x000000077f2db0>
```

The question is, how can I use the helper method when running RSpec testing? And am I using the helper method correctly?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I do some googling about how to call helper methods inside models and found a solution and changed my model into this:

```
class FinancialManager::SalaryRecord::SomeRecord < ApplicationRecord
  validates :level,
            presence: true,
            inclusion: {
              in: ApplicationController.helpers.levels
            },
            numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

The system and the RSpec run well

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer to your question, I was struggling to find how to invoke helpers from a factory callback and this worked. +1. You should accept your own answer ^^